# Нужно спроектировать базу данных где будут таблицы доктор и специальности

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

Нужно на Laravel спроектировать базу данных где есть **доктора** и **специальности**,
специальности **заданны автоматически**  благодаря `--seed`,

Помогите спроектировать связи между таблицами ***doctor, specialities***

если ***одному доктору*** соответствует **только одна специальность**, но **одну и туже специальность** могут иметь ***много докторов***  .

Если можно напишите подробно ***какая здесь связь между таблицами*** и дайте **ссылку на документацию Laravel** .

Comment: А что тут сложного? Есть таблица специализаций, в которой id/название профессии/etc.уникальны. в таблице докторов каждый доктор имеет поле специализации, где и стоит уникальный параметр из таблицы специализаций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
doctor(id, name, description)
specialities (id, title, description)
set_specialities(id, id_specialities, id_doctor)
```

Второй вариант:

```
doctor(id, id_specialities, name, description)
specialities (id, title, description)
```

Как дальше работать со связями [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: Второй вариант то что надо .  Но  для связи таблиц нужно ли мне в migration   create_doctors_table  указать foreign_key  или   это автоматически делается  методом belongsTo

Comment: Я всегда в таблице создаю ключи, так что в миграции добавьте создание ключа. Первый вариант позволит, в дальнейшем, присваивать докторам несколько специальнойстей

Comment: Забыл про belongsTo написать )) он не создает ключи, а работает с ними для связи, есть еще момент если приложение будет рассчитано на большую нагрузку, в отношения добавляйте метод select, и вызывайте только нужные поля из таблиц, это снизит нагрузку